# How to identify all global temporary tables

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I need to identify **which tables in my schema are Global Temporary Tables**.
Following script returns names of all my tables, but *I am not able to identify which of these are GTTs and which are not*.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE')
AND OWNER='owner_name';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`ALL_TABLES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286)

```
select table_name
from all_tables
where TEMPORARY = 'Y'
AND OWNER='owner_name';
```

`Temporary` column indicates whether the table is temporary (`Y`) or not (`N`)